# How to loosen cable tension in disc brakes

Tags: disc-brake

I have a Victory VEGASJACKPOT bike with cable disk brakes, and I need to loosen my cable tension. How do you do this? I've already done it all the way on the screw/knob by the brake lever.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following from [this website](http://www.cycle-systems-academy.co.uk/index.php/topics/brakes/cable-tension-and-setting-brakes/tensioning-a-cable-disc-brake), and if you go to the website there are pictures as well.

> On the actual brake, loosen the caliper fixing bolts with an allen
>   key, both top and bottom. Once you do that feed the cable through the
>   brake caliper from the barrel adjuster at the top of the caliper
>   through the fixing bolt at the bottom, and once you have achieved the
>   correct tension then fix it down by tightening the bolt with an allen
>   key. The next step is to squeeze the relevant lever whilst jiggling
>   the caliper sideways in order to help it find its best seated
>   position. Once you have done this, and keeping the relevant lever
>   squeezed, you can now tighten the top and bottom caliper fixing bolts.
>   After this, you will need to back up the inner dial (fixed pad) a
>   couple of clicks before ending up with the brake pad in the middle of
>   the caliper.